# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, requestanimationframe

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong with my use of requestAnimationFrame here as it appears to be working but it's throwing this error.

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.

I'm trying to rotate an element by 90 degrees every 3000ms and then fadeIn/Out some other elements. This might not be the most graceful way of doing this, I suspect it isn't, my understanding of JS is rather basic. So if any one can explain what's causing this error I'd really appreciate it.

```
var iteration = 0,
    degrees = 0;   

function rotate_by_90(degrees, iteration) {
    if(iteration <= 3) {
        var deg = degrees - 90,
            new_deg = deg;

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#rotate').css('transform', 'translateZ(-60px) rotateX(' + deg + 'deg');
            console.log(new_deg + ' degrees');
            iteration++;
            console.log(iteration + ' iteration');
            requestAnimationFrame(rotate_by_90(new_deg, iteration));            
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        $('#rotating_text').fadeOut();
        $('#animation_overlay').fadeIn();
    }
};

requestAnimationFrame(rotate_by_90(degrees,iteration));
```

The HTML

```
<div id="rotating_text" class="rotating_text">
    <span>Some text </span>
    <div class="rotate_container">
        <div id="rotate" class="rotate">
            <span>thing 1</span>
            <span>thing 2</span>
            <span>thing 3</span>
            <span>thing 4</span>
        </div>                              
    </div>
</div>  

<div id="animation_overlay" class="animation_overlay">                      
    <span>Some stuff</span>
</div>
```

Also, if anyone can suggest a better way of doing this (including looping this to start again once the whole thing is complete, that'd be extra appreciated!)

Answer (score 2):

No it's not working - you are calling `rotate_by_90` once yourself (immediately, not when the animation frame is ready!) and passing its return value (`undefined`) into `requestAnimationFrame`.Instead, you have to pass a *function* into `requestAnimationFrame` which the browser will call for you.

You can pass an anonymous function as well, so your code can be fixed by just adding `() =>` like this:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(() => rotate_by_90(degrees,iteration));
```

---

About how to possibly do this in a nicer way overall, may I suggest using async functions and an actual loop:

```js
// First, get some promisified versions of setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame:
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
const waitForAnimationFrame = () => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve))

// Next, our main function:
async function rotationAnimation () {
  let degrees = 0

  // Loop from 0 to 3
  for (let iteration = 0; iteration <= 3; iteration++) {
    // Update degrees
    degrees -= 90
    
    // Wait 3 seconds + animation frame
    await delay(3000)
    await waitForAnimationFrame()
    
    // Log variables
    console.log(`Iteration ${iteration}, ${degrees} degrees`)
    
    // Update the CSS
    $('#rotate').css('transform', `translateZ(-60px) rotate(${degrees}deg)`)
  }

  // After the loop is done, crossfade the elements
  $('#rotating_text').fadeOut()
  $('#animation_overlay').fadeIn()
}

// Call our main function, and handle rejections:
rotationAnimation().catch(e => console.error('Error during animation:', e))
```

```css
.rotate {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotating_text" class="rotating_text">
    <span>Some text </span>
    <div class="rotate_container">
        <div id="rotate" class="rotate">
            <span>thing 1</span>
            <span>thing 2</span>
            <span>thing 3</span>
            <span>thing 4</span>
        </div>                              
    </div>
</div>  

<div id="animation_overlay" class="animation_overlay">                      
    <span>Some stuff</span>
</div>
```

Note: I have kept your original logic of counting iterations separately, and starting with 0° but then immediately decreasing to -90° before first updating the element. However, I changed `rotateX` to `rotate` because otherwise the -90°/-270° states are invisible in the example because you are looking at the zero-width "edge" of the text.

(By the way, you could also do this whole thing using CSS animations only, without any JavaScript.)

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(rotate_by_90.bind(this, degrees, iteration))` would also work.

Comment: Yes but it's less intuitive to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really helpful, I've had to adapt it further now to add in some more animations but will use your suggestions as a starting point, thanks again!